# Intrincate variable generation with conditionals against multiple factor variables in R

Tags: r, dataframe, refactoring, pipeline, recode

I'm triying to generate a new variable using multiple conditionals that evaluate against factor variables.

So, let's say I got this factor variables data.frame

```
x<-c("1", "2", "1","NA", "1", "2", "NA", "1", "2", "2", "NA" )

y<-c("1","NA", "2", "1", "1", "NA", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1" )

z<-c("1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3", "4", "1", "2", "3")

w<- c("01", "02", "03", "04","05", "06", "07", "01", "02", "03", "04")


df<-data.frame(x,y,z,w)

df$x<-as.factor(df$x)
df$y<-as.factor(df$y)
df$z<-as.factor(df$z)
df$w<-as.factor(df$w)

str(df)
```

So I need to get a new v colum on my dataframe which takes values between 1, 0 or `NA` with the following conditionals:

Takes value 1 if: x = "1", y = "1", z = "1" or "2", w = "01" to "06"

Takes value 0 if it doesn't meet at least one of the conditionals.

Takes value `NA` if any of x, y, z, or w is `NA`.

Had tried using a pipe `%>%` along `mutate` and `case_when` but have been unable to make it work.

So my desired result would be a new column `v` in `df` which would look like this:

`[1]  1 NA  0 NA  1 NA NA  0  0  0 NA`

Comment: Why the eighth entry is "1"? The corresponding `z` is not "1" or "2"

Comment: Probably my misstake, thanks for pointing it out. Just edited for the sake of any other viewers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I also use `mutate` with `case_when`. Since the `NA` in your dataset is of character "NA" (literal string of "NA"), we cannot use function like `is.na()` to idenify it. Would recommend to change it to "real" `NA` (by removing double quotes in your input).

As I've pointed out in the comment, I'm not sure why the eighth entry is "1" when the corresponding `z` is not "1" or "2".

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(v = case_when(x == "1" & y == "1" & z %in% c("1", "2") & w %in% paste0(0, seq(1:6)) ~ "1",
                            x == "NA" | y == "NA" | z  == "NA" | w  == "NA" ~ NA_character_, 
                            T ~ "0"))

    x  y z  w    v
1   1  1 1 01    1
2   2 NA 2 02 <NA>
3   1  2 3 03    0
4  NA  1 4 04 <NA>
5   1  1 1 05    1
6   2 NA 2 06 <NA>
7  NA  2 3 07 <NA>
8   1  1 4 01    0
9   2  2 1 02    0
10  2  1 2 03    0
11 NA  1 3 04 <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort, this do the job it just fine. Would you mind to put the code if there were real NA?.

Comment: Just replace the second condition with `is.na(x) | is.na(y) | is.na(z) | is.na(w) ~ NA_character_, `